# cities and distance by latitude-longitude

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with:

city
latitude
longitude

And I need a sql query to know all cities are 100 miles from new york.

Comment: Btw I strongly advice you to accept answers to your questions. Otherwise people won't help you that much. Just have a look at your questions and accept those answers that helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL
It is a nice introduction. Or just google for `mysql distance queries`, you will find some tutorials.

If you have the possibility and want to have it easier, switch to [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) which supports distance queries out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Here's ours.  You may need to modify it for your table structure.  Ours looks up retail locations (and amenities), not cities, but the hard part is the "closest by distance" which works in this statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNearbyLocations] @CenterLatitude FLOAT, @CenterLongitude FLOAT
AS

DECLARE @CntXAxis FLOAT 
DECLARE @CntYAxis FLOAT 
DECLARE @CntZAxis FLOAT 

SET @CntXAxis = COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude)) 
SET @CntYAxis = COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude)) 
SET @CntZAxis = SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) 

SELECT LocationId, LocationName, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Latitude, Longitude,
               hasATM, hasCarWash, hasDiesel, hasE85, is24hr, hasTrendar, hasWiFi, isTravelCenter, isMiniTravelCenter, isTruckerFriendly, hasScale, hasHotFood,
               ProxDistance = 3961 * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(latitude, longitude)*@CntXAxis + dbo.YAxis(latitude, longitude)*@CntYAxis + dbo.ZAxis(latitude)*@CntZAxis) 
FROM Locations 
WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY ProxDistance ASC
GO
```

**Edit - added (sorry I missed these originally)**

```
-- USER-DEFINED FUNCTIONS
-- XAxis #########################################
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XAxis] (@lat float, @lon float)  
RETURNS float
AS  
BEGIN 
   RETURN COS(4 * (4 * atn2(1, 5) - atn2(1, 239)) / 180 * @lat) * COS(4 * (4 * atn2(1, 5) - atn2(1, 239)) / 180 * @lon) 
END
```

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[YAxis] (@lat float, @lon float)  
RETURNS float AS  
BEGIN 
RETURN COS(4 * (4 * atn2(1,5) - atn2(1,239)) / 180 * @lat) * SIN(4 * (4 * atn2(1,5) - atn2(1,239)) / 180 * @lon)
END
```

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ZAxis] (@lat float)  
RETURNS float AS  
BEGIN 
RETURN SIN(4 * (4 * atn2(1,5) - atn2(1,239)) / 180 * @lat)
END
```

Comment: If there are many potential records (which would impact query efficiency), you'll want to prune the results to those within the bounding rectangle for the reference point (NYC), then do the distance formula to see if a candidate city lies within the circular distance.

Comment: What is `dbo.XAxis(latitude, longitude)`? Did you define an `XAxis` FUNCTION? (similarly for YAxis and ZAxis)

Comment: @Ortwin Gentz - updated my answer.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I forgot to include those.

Comment: Thanks. The solutions looks rather complicated though and I fear that performance isn't that great with all the stored procedures. In my tests, I observed a significant speed gain by getting rid of procedure calls in ORDER BY parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need the lat long of NYC, or whichever city you want to analyze against. then simply measure miles between the two set of coordinates using math. In Excel the formula is

```
getDistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2)
```

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88484/excel-distance-calculation