# Get surronding places in  SQL 

Tags: mysql, sql, latitude-longitude

I have database of different hotels for different cities. Each hotel has latitude and longitude.

Can I fetch surrounding hotels, let's say within 25 kilometers by SQL.
I am using mySQL.

Comment: don't forget that longitude is non linear

Comment: @Seph, What do you want to say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cities and distance by latitute-longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233196/cities-and-distance-by-latitute-longitude)

Comment: You can find solutions at the duplicate question(s).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, that is different type of question. See carefully. huh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, run this in console mode. It will create a new MySQL function (see below for phpMyAdmin).

```
DELIMITER |
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GPS_Distance_Meters|
CREATE FUNCTION GPS_Distance_Meters (lat1 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE rlo1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rlo2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlo DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dla DOUBLE;
    DECLARE a DOUBLE;

    SET rlo1 = RADIANS(lng1);
    SET rla1 = RADIANS(lat1);
    SET rlo2 = RADIANS(lng2);
    SET rla2 = RADIANS(lat2);
    SET dlo = (rlo2 - rlo1) / 2;
    SET dla = (rla2 - rla1) / 2;
    SET a = SIN(dla) * SIN(dla) + COS(rla1) * COS(rla2) * SIN(dlo) * SIN(dlo);
    RETURN (6378137 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1 - a)));
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Or you can run this in phpMyAdmin but remember to change delimiter to | instead of ;

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GPS_Distance_Meters|
CREATE FUNCTION GPS_Distance_Meters (lat1 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE rlo1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rlo2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlo DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dla DOUBLE;
    DECLARE a DOUBLE;

    SET rlo1 = RADIANS(lng1);
    SET rla1 = RADIANS(lat1);
    SET rlo2 = RADIANS(lng2);
    SET rla2 = RADIANS(lat2);
    SET dlo = (rlo2 - rlo1) / 2;
    SET dla = (rla2 - rla1) / 2;
    SET a = SIN(dla) * SIN(dla) + COS(rla1) * COS(rla2) * SIN(dlo) * SIN(dlo);
    RETURN (6378137 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1 - a)));
END|
```

Now to use the function. Example :

```
    SELECT *
    FROM restaurants 
    WHERE GPS_Distance_Meters('48.858205', '2.294359', lat, lng) < 1000 ORDER BY proximite ASC 
    LIMIT 10
```

Here we search for **limit 10** results from 48.858205, 2.294359 (compared to field lat and lng) within 1000 meters (1KM).

Comment: What is the first section? PHPmyadmin returned Error on executing the first part. plz

Comment: Change delimiter to | instead of ; and use the second section in my post to use it with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Not at all. I m sure mysql does not support such queries.

Comment: It does. I use it on my website. What is the error ? Try in console mode.

Comment: Query:  SELECT * AS proximite FROM shk_resturants WHERE GPS_Distance_Meters('48.858205', '2.294359', latitude, longitute) < 1000 ORDER ...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS proximite 
    FROM shk_resturants 
    WHERE GPS_Distance_Meters('48.85820' at line 2

Execution Time : 0 sec

Comment: **< 1000** is 1000 meter so 1 kilometer. 25000 so... **GPS_Distance_Meters('48.858205', '2.294359', lat, lng) < 25000** will be 25 kM. Working ? And be sure to set your own GPS coordonates.

Comment: Oh and 6378137 is the radius of earth in meters. Is it working ? If it is please mark it as answered. I am sure it will help people in near future.

Comment: Davide point to ponder:
place 1) long: 31.552278760192  lat: 74.338372290294
place 2) long: 74.354515151064  lat: 31.538375655693
These tow places re located within 100KM of my own city. But it cant be displayed within any range you enter 100, 1000 100000 ???

Comment: It is in meters so 1000 = 1 KM. Get a GPS point from one of your hotel data. Look this : http://data.imagup.com/11/1134278780.jpg